# Using ```FILTERXML``` Function with structure without </>

Tags: excel, xml, excel-formula

In MS Excel 2019, I have used the WEBSERVICE function to obtain the following output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root response="True"><animal name="dog" fur="red" bitey="yes"/></root>.
```

I would like to use the `FILTERXML`function to extract `animal name` (containing spaces), `fur`, and `bitey` as separate columns. There will only be one entry in each XML, but there will be separate WEBSERVICE returns in each row.

I have seen multiple examples for this function, but they all seem to expect a different format, something like:

```
<movie>
  <title>Inception</title>
  <title>The Dark Knight</title>
</movie>
```

That is, with the content that should be extracted wrapped between `<title>` and `</title>`, which is not the format I receive.

I also found online the example

```
<cities>
  <NorthAmerica city="Vancouver" country="Canada"/>
  <NorthAmerica city="Seattle" country="USA"/>
</cities>
```

Where the function `=FILTERXML(B3,"//NorthAmerica/@city")` should return  `{"Vancouver";"Seattle"}` (as an output over two cells).

However, I have not been able to replicate this via `=FILTERXML(B3,"//NorthAmerica/@city")`.

I could replicate that, but I could not find the correct `xpath` format that would extract the information from my xml, e.g. `//root/@bitey`.

Is my output not XML? Is it a different type of XML? Does it need to be translated?

Comment: `=FILTERXML(A1,"//animal/@name")` returns the name or the full path `=FILTERXML(A1,"root/animal/@name")`

Comment: Thank you. I had not realized that ```animal``` was not part of ```animal name```.